# Expanding partition (xfs) of a virtual machine

Tags: hard-drive, partition, partition-table

OS: Ubuntu 14.04, partition table:

```
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 37.6GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      1049kB  200MB   199MB   primary   xfs             boot
2      200MB   1201MB  1000MB  primary   linux-swap(v1)
3      1201MB  2201MB  1000MB  primary   xfs
4      2202MB  26.8GB  24.6GB  extended
5      2202MB  8201MB  5999MB  logical   xfs
6      8202MB  26.8GB  18.6GB  logical   xfs
```

I'm trying to expand one (#6) of the partitions on a virtual machine. The VM is located on an ESXi where i raised the current disk with 10GB of diskspace. `parted` recognises the new space but when I try to resize the partition it gives me:

```
(parted) resizepart 6
End?  [26.8GB]? 37.6GB
Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.
```

If I instead try to remove and create a new partition in its place, I recieve the below message as if it's remembering the previous partition?:

```
(parted) rm 6
(parted) mkpart
Partition type?  [logical]?
File system type?  [ext2]? xfs
Start? 8202MB
End? 37.6GB
Warning: You requested a partition from 8202MB to 37.6GB.
The closest location we can manage is 8202MB to 26.8GB.
Is this still acceptable to you?
Yes/No?
```

I'm not sure how to get the new space allocated to my partition 6? Let me know if any details are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend the extended partition (4) first. Then you can extend/replace the logical ones.

Comment: Oh god! You just saved my day :-). I completely forgot about that - and my partition is now expanded. THANK YOUUUU!

Comment: You're welcome. Tip: make partition 4 a normal one and make it a LVM physical volume with `pvcreate`. Then you can easily extend volumes. You may want to read up on LVM.